# the components do not re-render

Tags: reactjs, redux, render, redux-saga

so I have a form with multiple select options.
[The form I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiw8d.png)

I select an option from the year which dispatches an action and makes api call to get list of brands which is displayed.

if I select a brand and try to select another year, doesn't it have to make another api call when it is selected? but the same list of brands are shown?

inside my render function:

```
<div className='form-div'>
    <Select defaultValue='-Year-' style = {{width:262}} className = 'formInput' onChange={this.handleYearSelection.bind(this)}>
      {getYear(this.props.year)}
    </Select>
    </div>
    <div className='form-div'>
    <Select defaultValue='Brand' disabled={!this.state.brandVisibility} style = {{width:129}} className = 'formInput' onChange={this.handleBrandSelection.bind(this)}>
      {getBrand(this.props.brand)}
    </Select>
    <Select defaultValue='Model' disabled={!this.state.modelVisibility} style = {{width:129}} className = 'formInput' onChange={this.handleModelSelection.bind(this)}>
      {getModel(this.props.model)}
    </Select>
  </div>
```

before render function:

```
handleYearSelection(year){
    this.setState({brandVisibility : true, year: year});
    this.props.requestYear(year);
  }

  handleBrandSelection(brand){
    this.setState({modelVisibility : true, brand: brand });
    this.props.requestBrand(brand);
  }
```

So, how can I solve this

Comment: onChange() dispatches an event, so your `brand` parameter will not have the desired value. Can you see the change in state in your React devtools?

Comment: I tried to recreate your form using your code and lots of imagination :D https://codesandbox.io/s/k321xvv77o. I don't think the root cause of the problem is in the code you gave us. If you could perhaps fork my sandbox and modify it so the issue is reproducible, we could help you bit more.

Comment: I have similar code as yours. But the saga is called only the first time. it doesn't when i try to change the year. The state changes though